# Creating a user in Oracle 11g - No permissions issue

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to set up a user in my Oracle 11g database as such

```
create user BARRY6 IDENTIFIED by password123;
grant connect to BARRY6;
grant create session to BARRY6;
grant  UNLIMITED TABLESPACE  to BARRY6;
commit;
```

This should create the user and provides them with the basic permissions.
All commands executes  successfully, However i can not connect with this user.
I get an error

```
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

    ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
    01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
    *Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
               the necessary privileges.
    *Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
               administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
    Vendor code 1031
```

When i view the `USER_ROLE_PRIVS` table , there is no permissions in that table for my user

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because the role i was trying to login in as was sysdba. While it should be default.

I know, stupid, but it posting the solution in case other people are creating a user and they make this simple mistake. It was caused by loading the sys connection and just changing the password and not changing the role